# Reaching out to a method outside of an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and i'm trying to call within the swipe event, the method this.swipe which triggers whatever function. The thing is that it does not know what is this.swipe in the context this.carousel.swipe. How can i trigger this function ?

```
PM.SwipeCarousel = function (carouselSelector) {
this.carousel = $j(carouselSelector);

this.carousel.swipe({
  swipe : this.swipe
})

// method to call
this.swipe = function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
   console.log(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData);
  }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to pass the method before you have created it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested code should have been

```
PM.SwipeCarousel = function (carouselSelector) {
this.carousel = $j(carouselSelector);

// method to call
this.swipe = function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
   console.log(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData);
  }

this.carousel.swipe({
  swipe : this.swipe
})
```

}